# How do you stop the PocketBook system from closing your program?

Tags: arm, background-process

I'm writing a program for my PocketBook Lux 3.

When I run the program, located in `/mnt/ext1/applications/`, it runs but immediately closes.

How do I keep it running in the background?

Code in https://gitgud.io/yuvallanger/WebPBTerm/blob/master/main.go

Comment: At the very least you should show the source code. Most programs close when they simply... end.

Comment: A simple shell script located in `/mnt/ext1/applications/sleep.app`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 999
```

Stays working and visible in the Task Manager. Now I need to figure out how to mimic what `sleep` does in the golang program.